# Changing CPU frequency programmatically

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, cpu, cpu-frequency

I have seen that standard CPU Frequency driver(comes with default package with linux kernel) can change the CPU frequency at runtime, when being used under the supervision of "Ondemand" governor.

What I want is to write a module, which is supposed to increase/decrease the CPU frequency under certain condition. I could not find any way to do it...

Any help in this context will be appreciated...

Thank you